# How is it possible to paint more than one rectangle on a glass pane?

Tags: java, swing, glasspane

I am trying to paint a series of rectangles on the glass pane as described in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane). the thing is that only the last element from my list is being displayed on the pane.

Does anyone how to be able to paint more then one rectangle on the same pane?

The following is the code being used:

paint method in the pane's class , extending JComponent

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (point != null) {

            int value = this.getGradient();


            Color myColour = new Color(255, value, 0, 175);
            g.setColor(myColour);
            g.fillRect(point.x - 13, point.y - 15, this.width, this.height);

        }
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `Graphics g = container.getGraphics();`  That is immediately suspect, though I'll wait for an SSCCE before commenting further.

Comment: +1, for this question, made me learn something new :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no intrinsic limit on painting on the glass pane, other than the clipping boundary. For example, try the following in `MyGlassPane`.

[image: glass pane demo]

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (point != null) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(point.x, point.y, 60, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawRect(point.x, point.y, 20, 60);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I was not painting all of the rectangles in this method, but I was calling it several times.. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you're calling `paintComponent()` directly, consider calling `repaint()` instead.

Comment: nice, because I was sure untill this moment that Glass/RootPane is about paint (API and another rubbish..) not paintComponent :-), right, excelent

Comment: @mKorbel: I had to look, too. :-)